# I have this IF saying that: if the index of the string is == 0 then make it UpperCase, but the output is index 0 in lowercase

Tags: javascript, string, indexing, uppercase, lowercase

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let newStr = ''
  
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++){

    if(str[i] == 0){
      newStr += str[i].toUpperCase()//sets the first character of the String to uppercase
    } else if (str[i - 1] == ' '){
      newStr += str[i].toUpperCase();//sets every character that has a space before it to uppercase
    } else {
      newStr += str[i].toLowerCase();//sets any other character to lowercase
    }

  } return newStr 

}


console.log(titleCase("I'm a liTTle tea pot")); // output: i'm A Little Tea Pot
```

Comment: `str[i]` will never equal `0`. It's a character (letter/string), not a number; It could be `"0"` but not `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if(str[i] == 0)` should be `if(i === 0)` otherwise the check will be if the first character in the string is a zero

Answer (score 2):

You need to check if the first index i.e `i` to be `0` or not, But you are checking equality for the character at `0` i.e `I`.

Since `I` is not equal to `0` so it skips the match.

So you need to change from

```
 if(str[i] == 0){
```

to

```
if (i === 0) {
```

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  let newStr = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      newStr += str[i].toUpperCase(); //sets the first character of the String to uppercase
    } else if (str[i - 1] == " ") {
      newStr += str[i].toUpperCase(); //sets every character that has a space before it to uppercase
    } else {
      newStr += str[i].toLowerCase(); //sets any other character to lowercase
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a liTTle tea pot"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is with the if condition because currently is uses the value at index 0 not the index
The correct condition is

```
if(i==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first if condition you should change it to compare with i, not with str[i]. str[i] will not equal zero it is returning the first character of the string.

```
if(i == 0){newStr += str[i].toUpperCase();}
```